# Re-enable Mac media keys originally disabled via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave

My Mac media keys are completely disabled. I originally disabled them far too long ago to remember how exactly I did it but I remember it was via the terminal that toggled a switch not available anywhere else.

To be more specific all of my function keys function properly without use of the fn keys and the media keys do nothing even with the fn keys.

Comment: What happens if you, in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard, toggle the "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" checkbox?

Comment: Checking that box does not allow me to use the media keys when pressing fn but all the others work

Comment: So whether or not it's checked and whether of not you press the fn key, the media keys never work, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to re-enable media keys you can use:

`launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist`

explained in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/274345/stop-itunes-from-launching-when-you-press-play-on-your-macs-keyboard/)